# Watson Retrieve and Rank does not return any document though Content and Questions are populated

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am getting [image: Error when asking "What is JUnit? question, Ranker is specified]

Retrieve and Rank failed to handle question even though documents and training questions with answers are available as shown follows : 
[image]

and the Questions are as follows :
[image]

Thank you,
Sandhya

Answer (score 1):

The full error being returned by the Retrieve and Rank service that is causing this is:

> Can not rerank results. Verify your query does not contain any special
>   characters or that your schema has not changed in incompatible ways

(*Although this isn't being well handled by the UI. We'll improve that, so thanks for letting us know.*)

What it means is that you're using submitting queries and requesting that they be sorted by a ranker that was trained/created with a different collection, with a different configuration and schema. That doesn't work.

It is possible to use a ranker across different collections, but not in such circumstances. As I say, we'll improve the UI to make this clearer in future.

But for now, the reason you're not getting results is because that ranker you're trying to use cannot be used with this particular collection, because they are incompatible. Once you've collected enough of a ground truth to train a ranker for this particular collection, with it's own config and schema, you'll be able to submit queries using that new ranker just fine.

Comment: Thank you, Dale. Is it correct that I cannot get a dedicated ranker without 150+ questions ?

Comment: From the tooling, yes - it'll start letting you train rankers after you've rated answers for 150 questions

Comment: I have 80 questions uploaded , can I create a ranker in any other way e.g. using cURL command ?

Comment: Manually preparing the ground truth to train a ranker without the tooling is really a separate question. It'd be better to mark this as accepted and create a new question for help with that if you have any problems with the documentation for that (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.shtml) rather than make this one SO question a catch-all.